# JUnit Test with switch-case

Tags: java, testing, junit, switch-statement

I still new to `Junit` test. I have a switch-case as code below.

```
public void manageTrans(ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc) {
        AbcEntry abcEntry = new AbcEntry();
        abcEntry.setEntryMid(isoMsgZxc.getMid());

        String mti = isoMsgZxc.getMti() + "." + isoMsgZxc.getProcessingCode().substring(0, 2);
        String transType = "";
        BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal("00.000");

        switch (mti) {
            case "1234.14":
            case "0212.02":
                transType = "S";
                amt = new BigDecimal(isoMsgZxc.getTransactionAmount()).negate();
                break;
            case "0400.20":
            case "0200.22":
                transType = "R";
                amt = new BigDecimal(isoMsgZxc.getTransactionAmount());
                break;
        }

        abcEntry.setEntryType(transType);
        abcEntryRepository.saveAndFlush(abcEntry);
    }
```

Here how I testing it by using `@Test`

```
 @Test
    public void manageTrans() throws Exception {

        AbcEntry abcEntry = mock(abcEntry.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(AbcEntry.class).withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(abcEntry);

        ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc = new ISOMsgZxc();
        isoMsgZxc.setMti("0100");
        isoMsgZxc.setMid("0100");
        isoMsgZxc.setProcessingCode("000012");
        isoMsgZxc.setTransactionAmount("00.000");

        txnService.manageTrans(isoMsgZxc);

        verify(abcEntry).setEntryMid(isoMsgZxc.getMid());

        String asd = "0400.20";
        if(asd.equals("0400.20") || (mti.equals("0200.02")))
        {
            verify(abcEntry).setEntryType("R");
        }

        verify(abcEntryRepositoryMock).saveAndFlush(abcEntry);
    }
```

So far the testing show pass. But are there any others method to test the `switch-case` ? What is the best way to test the switch case so all the possible value can be tested? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `amt` seems never to be used and `jcbEntry` is probably `abcEntry`? In general you should test one scenario per test method. Since all cases are different scenarios it is quite ok to write three tests. And each test would look like the one you wrote. Maybe you should replace the mock of jcbentry by a true object (less fragile).

Comment: @CoronA can I write `switch-case` in testing ?

Comment: You could ... but you should not. I will code what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to test `manageTrans`, but in a strange fashion due to the structure of your code (mixing business and persistence logic).

You could have a `generateEntry(ISOMsgZxc)` which creates and returns the `AbcEntry`:

```
public AbcEntry generateEntry(ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc) {
        AbcEntry abcEntry = new AbcEntry();
        abcEntry.setEntryMid(isoMsgZxc.getMid());

        String mti = isoMsgZxc.getMti() + "." + isoMsgZxc.getProcessingCode().substring(0, 2);
        String transType = "";
        BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal("00.000");

        switch (mti) {
            case "1234.14":
            case "0212.02":
                transType = "S";
                amt = new BigDecimal(isoMsgZxc.getTransactionAmount()).negate();
                break;
            case "0400.20":
            case "0200.22":
                transType = "R";
                amt = new BigDecimal(isoMsgZxc.getTransactionAmount());
                break;
        }

        abcEntry.setEntryType(transType);
        return abcEntry;
}
```

This will allow you to test `generateEntry` to verify the entry after:

```
@Test
public void generateEntry() {
    ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc = new ISOMsgZxc();
    isoMsgZxc.setMti("0100");
    isoMsgZxc.setMid("0100");
    isoMsgZxc.setProcessingCode("000012");
    isoMsgZxc.setTransactionAmount("00.000");

    AbcEntry entry = txnService.generateEntry(isoMsgZxc);

    //verfiy
    verify(abcEntry).setEntryMid(isoMsgZxc.getMid());

    Map<String, String> expectedValues = new HashMap<>();
    expectedValues.put("0400.20", "R");
    expectedValues.put("0200.02", "R");
    //...

    expectedValues.forEach((input, output) -> verify(input).setEntryType(output));
}
```

In your production code, simply call:

```
entryRepo.saveAndFlush(generateEntry())
```

Easier to maintain (room for validation), easier to test (concerns are separated).

---

Assuming you want to test the persistence part, you should create another test.

`manageTrans` would look like this:

```
public void manageTrans(ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc) {
    AbcEntry entry = generateEntry();
    entryRepo.saveAndFlush(entry);
}
```

And your test would simply check if the entry exists in the repo after calling `manageTrans`. Although chances are, `saveAndFlush` has already been tested, so the `manageTrans` really wouldn't need testing, as it's implementation consists of already-tested code, and there is no special integration required.

Comment: Really nice. If you add a sentence that this does also avoid to use PowerMock (which is a good thing!) ... you got the perfect answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The test for the third test case could look like this.

```
@Test
public void manageTrans() throws Exception {
    ISOMsgZxc isoMsgZxc = new ISOMsgZxc();
    isoMsgZxc.setMti("0200");
    isoMsgZxc.setMid("0100");
    isoMsgZxc.setProcessingCode("220012"); 
    isoMsgZxc.setTransactionAmount("00.000");
    //mti should now be = 0200.00, the third case

    txnService.manageTrans(isoMsgZxc);

    assertThat(abcEntry.getEntryMid(), equalTo(isoMsgZxc.getMid()));
    assertThat(abcEntry.getEntryType(), equalTo("R"));

    verify(jcbEntryRepositoryMock).saveAndFlush(jcbEntry);
}
```

To cover the other test cases:

- modify the two lines  `isoMsgZxc.setMti("0200");` and `isoMsgZxc.setProcessingCode("220012");` such that they enter the correct case
- you will need 5 tests for full coverage

Comment: I have 4 cases, the four cases should write like the example you gave ?

Comment: 4 cases and the case that none matches - see the anweser of @sbjavateam

Comment: Why write switch case in testing not advisable?

Comment: not advisable -> your test become hard to change , hard to support , hard .....   just do some refactoring in your test and you will see , it will be bigger  but easy to use

Comment: A test should setup a fixed scenario and verify the results from calling a certain method. Loops, conditionals and switches mean that there is something variable in your test. If the test fails you will have to debug which iteration/conditional/switch caused the failure. Having a test for each scenario will let exactly that scenario fail, that is does not as expected.

Comment: so my 4 cases can look like the code you given, just change the few lines ?

Comment: Could be a valid solution.